# Subsetting a value in a string variable using if statement

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-transform

I have the following dataset where I have subj_id's representing participants, trial_type representing whether it is a practice trial or the actual experimental trial (i.e., test), and my dependent variable indicated as DV.

I need to write an if statement where I only want to include participants (i.e., subj_id) whose Practice 3 DV is bigger than Practice 4 DV. So, adding another column such as 'include' where participant 1 should get a value of 1 indicating that they should be kept in the further processing and participant 2 should get a value of 0 indicating that they shouldn't be kept.

I know how to subset something like `trial_type > 60` etc. but I don't know how to subset a value in a column with if statements.

| subj_id | trial_type | DV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Practice1 | 67 |
| 1 | Practice2 | 3 |
| 1 | Practice3 | 78 |
| 1 | Practice4 | 14 |
| 1 | Test | 97 |
| 1 | Test | 65 |
| 1 | Test | 28 |
| 1 | Test | 16 |
| 1 | Test | 97 |
| 1 | Test | 35 |
| 2 | Practice1 | 100 |
| 2 | Practice2 | 99 |
| 2 | Practice3 | 99 |
| 2 | Practice4 | 100 |
| 2 | Test | 29 |
| 2 | Test | 18 |
| 2 | Test | 33 |
| 2 | Test | 46 |
| 2 | Test | 87 |
| 2 | Test | 95 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Sample data

```
 df <-
    tibble::tribble(
      ~subj_id, ~trial_type,  ~DV,
            1L, "Practice1",  67L,
            1L, "Practice2",   3L,
            1L, "Practice3",  78L,
            1L, "Practice4",  14L,
            1L,      "Test",  97L,
            1L,      "Test",  65L,
            1L,      "Test",  28L,
            1L,      "Test",  16L,
            1L,      "Test",  97L,
            1L,      "Test",  35L,
            2L, "Practice1", 100L,
            2L, "Practice2",  99L,
            2L, "Practice3",  99L,
            2L, "Practice4", 100L,
            2L,      "Test",  29L,
            2L,      "Test",  18L,
            2L,      "Test",  33L,
            2L,      "Test",  46L,
            2L,      "Test",  87L,
            2L,      "Test",  95L
      )
```

### Create variable include

```
df %>% 
  #Grouping by subject
  group_by(subj_id) %>% 
  #Create a new variable: DV practice 3 > DV practice 4, by subject
  mutate(
    include = if_else(DV[trial_type == "Practice3"] > DV[trial_type == "Practice4"],1,0)
    )
```

[image]